# How can i write a response.binarywrite to a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, binaryfiles

I am having my data saved in my database as Longblob and while saving i am converting it to bytes and saving now while retrieving we can have that data by writing as follows

```
 Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Data"];
                    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
```

But what i need is i need that data in bytes to be represented as string is it possible

Comment: Is the binary data just string character codes (like ASCII or UTF-8/16), or is it encoded in some fashion (e.g. BASE 64)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, *is* the data an encoded string? If so, use something like

```
string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

... but make sure you use the right encoding.

If it's arbitrary binary data though, you should use base64 instead:

```
string text = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

That will get you an entirely-ASCII string which can be converted back to the original byte array using `Convert.FromBase64String`.

Without knowing what your data is, it's impossible to say which of these approaches is appropriate. You say you're converting your data to bytes when you save - but you haven't said *how* you've converted your data to bytes. Basically you want to reverse that process, whatever it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use an encoding to convert it back.

```
string text = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myByteArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can convert arrays of bytes to strings by using the System.Text.Encoding.GetString(byte[]) method, but you do need to specify which encoding the bytes are in. The CLR comes with a few default encodings (Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.ASCII, etc) but in general you need to be very aware of what encoding was used to encode the data.